# Approving documents created by external users in SharePoint online

Tags: sharepoint-online, workflow, external-users

I'm not sure if this is intended or not, but the scenario is as follows: I have 4 accounts -

1. User 1(standard SPOnline account),
2. User 2(External account invited to  the site),
3. User 3(Approver),
4. User 4(Site collection admin).

I've set up a workflow to require approval for document creation in a library, when user 1 creates a document, both user 3 and user 4 can approve it. If user 2 creates a document, user 4 can approve it but user 3 lands on a "Sorry something went wrong" screen.

Not planning on making a habit of external users being able to create documents, but I'd like to be able to have the function available if I need to. Any ideas why the non-collection admin can't approve the document workflow?

Comment: What permission level have you assigned to the User 3?

Comment: the account has edit and read access to both the workflow task list, as well as the document list

Comment: oh dear, turns out I needed to add 'Approve' permissions to the document list as well, edit wasn't enough... that makes sense. Your comment made me have another look at the permissions though, thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

User 3 needs Approve access to the document list, edit access is not enough.